# How to make a select options binding default based on input conditions using a Knockout JS Array Map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am binding data to a Selection Option using a `Computed Observable` and `Array Map`.

Using the below code structure, how do I make a Country the default in the select option? For example: If a user is from `Albania` then set the default country to `Albania`. Note that I am using and need the selected value as argument for another function.

*Complete code:*

```
(function(){

    var self = this;

    self.SelectedCountry = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.CountryData = ko.observableArray([]);

    $.getJSON('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all', function(data){

        self.CountryData(data);

    });

    function viewModel(){

      // Add some possible logic to make country default based on input
      // from user. E.g. If data.alpha3Code === '1234'

        self.Countries = ko.computed(function () {
            return ko.utils.arrayMap(CountryData(),

                    function (data) {

                        return {

                            Name: data.name + ' ' + data.capital,
                            value: data.alpha3Code
                        }

                    });

        }).extend({notify: 'always'})
    }

    self.Location = ko.computed(function () {
        if (self.SelectedCountry()) {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(CountryData(), function (item) {
                return item.alpha3Code === self.SelectedCountry().value;
            });
        }
    });

    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());

})();
```

[Working example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dkr29b7u/):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong with your code here.

1. `SelectedCountry` should be an observable, not an observableArray
2. viewModel isn't properly a constructor function, and so shouldn't be called with `new` (I just got rid of it altogether)
3. You should be passing `self` to `applyBindings`
4. You probably want `optionsValue: 'value'` in your select bindings
5. `self` should be initialized to an empty object. `this` is the global object where you've done it. You probably meant to have it all inside your constructor.
6. You need `self` on the front of `CountryData` in your computeds.
7. Location should just return the name, not an array, because if `SelectedCountry` isn't defined, you have no array and your `[0]` breaks

With all of that out of the way, you just want to set the value of `SelectedCountry`, and the select will update accordingly. The only trick is, you need to add another binding, `valueAllowUnset: true` to the select to tell it your chosen value might not be there (which it won't, at least before the data is loaded).

```js
(function() {

  var self = {};

  self.SelectedCountry = ko.observable('BHR');
  self.CountryData = ko.observableArray([]);

  $.getJSON('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/all', function(data) {

    self.CountryData(data);

  });

  self.Countries = ko.computed(function() {
    return ko.utils.arrayMap(self.CountryData(),

      function(data) {

        return {

          Name: data.name + ' ' + data.capital,
          value: data.alpha3Code
        }

      });

  }).extend({
    notify: 'always'
  })

  self.Location = ko.computed(function() {
    if (self.SelectedCountry()) {
      var match = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.CountryData(), function(item) {
        return item.alpha3Code === self.SelectedCountry();
      })[0];
      if (match) {
        return match.name;
      }
    }
  });

  ko.applyBindings(self);

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<select data-bind="options: Countries, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'value', valueAllowUnset: true, value: SelectedCountry"></select>

<p>Welcome! You are from:</p> <span data-bind="text: Location()"></span>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the great answer and tips.